# Eclipse Format Comment

Tags: eclipse

Basically I want eclipse format

```
Some sample comments.
Second line.
Third line.
```

into

```
/* 
 * Some sample comments.
 * Second line.
 * Third line. 
 */
```

Any one know some quick ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a shortcut for this in eclipse use `ctrl` + `shift` + `/` (to apply block comment ) 
`ctrl` + `shift` + `\` (to remove block comment)

check [here](http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/add-comments-and-javadocs-in-eclipse-with-a-single-keystroke/)